# Css not inherited on child twig's template

Tags: css, twig

have an issue with my twig's templates, i explain.

I did linked the assets of my css that way : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">`

And it worked well on my nav.html.twig that is include on my base.html.twig but my issue is on my base.html.twig.

I did extended the base and put a nav.html.twig on my body block which is affected by my css file but the tags i put over on the body block aren't affected by css. Though it was the property on my animations that were wrong but even a background color isn't working.

base.html.twig :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Main Title{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}"> 
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'partials/nav.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{parent()}} - Main{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<section id="left-main">left test</section>
<section id="right-main">right test</section>

<div id="footer-block"></div>
{% include 'partials/footer.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your question mentions `not working in main.html.twig` but you've posted `index.html.twig` - Are those two the same?

Comment: Yes, you right, done a mistake on my message, it's the same, i edited it.

Comment: Should work as is then actually,  you're not overriding the block `stylesheets` inside the child template right?

Comment: no, i started writing the stylesheets before the block then add it in but had no effects. The strange fact is that the css working on the footer i made on the template but not on the "main" section of it.

Comment: I guess you also saw that i'm using bootstrap, just had to say.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but today it's working with the same code so i guess it's ok now.